# Incorrect values from a knockout observable array

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am working on a `web application` using `Asp.Net Mvc` in which I used knockout Js to retrieve and send data to Html View by performing some operation on the data.

For example I have the following data in my array named `datainput`

```
Grade Type Volume Price
A     Buy   1000   10
A     Sell  1200   10
B     Sell  100    100
```

I am computing an array which such that when displaying on a html page it just takes one distinct value of Grade and groups the data under that grade like

```
A
Buy 1000 10
Sell 1200 10

B
Sell 100 100
```

Used the above function as follows

```
self.uniqueSelect = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
            var Transactiontypes = ko.utils.arrayMap(self.datainput(), function (item) { return item.Grade })
            return ko.utils.arrayGetDistinctValues(Transactiontypes);
        });
```

I dont think there is an issue with above script, not sure though but I went ahead and used the data obtained from the above script and tried to populate it to html as follows

```
 <!--ko foreach: uniqueSelect-->

        <tr>
            <td class="clientproductHeader" data-bind="text: $data"></td>
            <td class="clientproductHeader" colspan="10"></td>
        </tr>


        <tbody data-bind="foreach: ko.observableArray($root.datainput()).extendsdistinct('Grade').index.Grade()[$data]">
<tr>
 <script type="text/html" id="read-template">

        <td data-bind="text: Type"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Volume"></td>
        <td  data-bind="text: (typeof Price() === 'number') ? Price().toFixed(2) : '' "></td>      

    </script>
</tr>

        </tbody>
        <!--/ko-->

    </table>
```

The above script for some reasons display duplicate data like if a Grade is repeated two times as in the example data it displays the same data of that grade two times and if it repeated three times then displays it thrice and so on.

I thought the error was with `<!--ko foreach: uniqueSelect-->` because it just loops the data depending on the number of similar grades.

results on html page are like

```
A
    Buy 1000 10
    Sell 1200 10

B
    Sell 100 100

A
    Buy 1000 10
    Sell 1200 10
```

In the above data Grade A is repeated twice so all the data with grade A is repeated twice where as grade B has just one entry and so, it happened only once
screen of data I received[image]
No clue how to deal with this

Comment: I would do the grouping with plain javascript, and then use KO to render that grouped data strucure. More readable, and less logic in presentation layer. For troubleshooting tips, sprinkle your code with console.log() and check your assumptions e.g. see if  `uniqueSelect` contains what you would expect

Comment: I threw together a [demo similar to the original approach](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/vnyymhmz/) for comparison. I'd lean toward the single pass data massage, if possible.

Comment: @Origineil The jsfiddle seems fine but my data is coming from database and when I pass datainput to the function you have, it doesn't work

Comment: Considering the data is giving issue both here and below can you edit into the original post a mocked-up example of the structure that you are receiving. Are you using the mapping-plugin?

Comment: @Origineil I have added screenshot of data on webpage provided there is nothing wrong with the data on the database

Answer (score 1):

I went through and wrote a version that does what I think you are trying to accomplish. It uses the method Pēteris described. [See it in action](http://plnkr.co/edit/DdGn4PL1P8W1FXzUd7tx?p=preview).

You want to keep the view code as simple as possible, and also be careful about reaching back into `$root`. If you are positive you would like to do it with a filter, make one that does a similar grouping as below, and then iterate over each of its entries/children. Also, try to avoid declaring observables in your views.

Finally, you could combine `groupByGrade()` and `getGrades()` into a single function that returns an object with a property for each of the results. It would save an iteration cycle.

The view:

```
<tr>
  <td class="clientproductHeader" data-bind="text: 'Grade ' + $data + ' (' + $root.log()[$data].length + ' trades)'"></td>
  <td class="clientproductHeader" colspan="10"></td>
</tr>


<tbody data-bind="foreach: $root.log()[$data]">
  <tr>
    <td data-bind="text: type"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: volume"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: (typeof price === 'number') ? price.toFixed(2) : '' "></td>
    <td class="actioncells">

      <a class="btn btn-success" title="Edit" data-bind="click: $root.edit">Edit</a>
    </td>

    <td class="actioncells">
      <a class="btn btn-danger" title="Delete " data-bind="click: $root.remove">Delete</a>
    </td>
  </tr>

</tbody>
<!--/ko-->
```

And the JavaScript:

```
function testViewModel() {

  // Underscore and Lo-dash both have a function to group
  // an object by key. That's what you want. Here is a
  // really simple version.
  function groupByGrade(data) {
    return data.reduce(function(last, next) {
      if (last[next.grade]) {
        last[next.grade].push(next);
      } else {
        last[next.grade] = [next];
      }
      return last;
    }, {});
  }

  // Get a unique list of the grades in the data to iterate over
  function getGrades(data) {
    return data.reduce(function(last, next) {
        return !!~last.indexOf(next.grade) ? last : last + next.grade;
    }, '').split('');
  }

  var rawData = [
    {
      grade: 'A',
      type: 'Buy',
      volume: 1000,
      price: 10
    }, {
      grade: 'A',
      type: 'Sell',
      volume: 1200,
      price: 10
    }, {
      grade: 'B',
      type: 'Sell',
      volume: 100,
      price: 100
    }
  ];

  console.log(getGrades(rawData));

  this.log    = ko.observable(groupByGrade(rawData));
  this.grades = ko.observableArray(getGrades(rawData));
}

ko.applyBindings(new testViewModel());
```

Comment: it returned some undefined values when I passed my datainput array to gerGrades function like  this.grades = ko.observableArray(getGrades(self.datainput()));

Comment: Can you give an example array? Even better, can you fork the Plunker and share a link? Hint: Youu can use `console.log(JSON.stringify(datainput))`